# Unity Ads AdMob Mediation Setup

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob, mobile-ad-mediation

For integrating Unity Ads within my AdMob mediation setup, I have followed this guide from first to last and follow exactly same steps:

[Integrating Unity Ads with Mediation](https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/mediation/unity)

Now I want to make sure whether I require to enable Unity Ads within Unity Services section or not??

[image]

I want to make sure whether I did proper setup for Unity Ads or not because other ad networks already integrated so I can't able to make sure all steps implemented properly.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? For me, turning on Unity Ads gives me a build error.

Comment: Okay, I will post here a solution that worked for me - give me some time to write here.

Comment: please post the answer if it worked for you.